# How to create a plot/graph showing percentage vegetation cover in R

Tags: r, plot

I collected data on vegetation cover across three transects at the same location in April and May (M=month, T=transect number, Q=quadrat number, V=percentage vegetation).

```
    M   T   Q   V
    apr 1   1   0
    apr 1   2   0
    apr 1   3   0
    apr 1   4   0
    apr 1   5   48
    apr 1   6   0
    apr 1   7   0
    apr 1   8   0
    apr 1   9   0
    apr 1   10  0
    apr 1   11  0
    apr 2   1   0
    apr 2   2   0
    apr 2   3   0
    apr 2   4   0
    apr 2   5   19
    apr 2   6   69
    apr 2   7   10
    apr 2   8   0
    apr 2   9   0
    apr 2   10  0
    apr 2   11  0
    apr 3   1   0
    apr 3   2   0
    apr 3   3   0
    apr 3   4   49
    apr 3   5   2
    apr 3   6   0
    apr 3   7   0
    apr 3   8   0
    apr 3   9   0
    apr 3   10  0
    apr 3   11  0
    may 1   1   0
    may 1   2   0
    may 1   3   0
    may 1   4   0
    may 1   5   52
    may 1   6   0
    may 1   7   0
    may 1   8   0
    may 1   9   0
    may 1   10  0
    may 1   11  0
    may 2   1   0
    may 2   2   0
    may 2   3   0
    may 2   4   0
    may 2   5   25
    may 2   6   85
    may 2   7   18
    may 2   8   0
    may 2   9   0
    may 2   10  0
    may 2   11  0
    may 3   1   0
    may 3   2   0
    may 3   3   0
    may 3   4   61
    may 3   5   7
    may 3   6   0
    may 3   7   0
    may 3   8   0
    may 3   9   0
    may 3   10  0
    may 3   11  0
```

I am looking to create a plot/graph in R which is similar to this one (but for one location):

I have no idea where to begin so any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: In given graph what does x-axis,y-axis and color mean?

Comment: Install `ggplot2` if you don't already have it and try (assuming you data is stored in a dataframe called df) `ggplot(df, aes(T, Q, fill = V)) + geom_raster() + facet_wrap(~M) + scale_fill_continuous(low = "white", high = "black")`

Comment: Thank you very much Relasta - it worked perfectly!